# Changing the class variable value or class property value via method called by an event not working Angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, events, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup

I'm new with angular 2, Currently facing a problem that I usually fixed with other languages.

The code below.

```
import { 
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  registerEvent
} from '../../utilities';

@Component({
  selector: 'mcs-slider-version2',
  templateUrl: './slider-version2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider-version2.component.scss']
})

export class SliderVersion2Component {

  private _isDragActivated: boolean;

  public constructor() {}

  public mouseDown(): void {
    console.log('down');
    this._isDragActivated = true;
    registerEvent(this._element, 'mousemove', this._onMouseMove);
    registerEvent(document, 'mouseup', this._mouseUp);
  }

  private _mouseUp(): void {
    this._isDragActivated = false;
    console.log(this._isDragActivate);
    console.log('removed');
  }

  private _onMouseMove(): void {
    if (this._isDragActivated) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    console.log(this._isDragActivated)
  }
}
```

Basically, my goal is once the `mousedown` event fired it will register two events on dom the `mousemove` and `mouseup` also it will set the property `_isDragActivated` as `true` means if the user move the mouse it will go/call to the method `_onMouseMove()` so basically it will console the value of the property `_isDragActivated` output `true` then if the user releases the mouse it will call/trigger the event `mouseup` on this method I set the property `_isDragActivated` as `false` and try to move the mouse again my expected output is `false` since I set it on `mouseup` event a while ago triggered however I constantly got an output `true` regardless how many times I triggered the `mouseup` event. Do I miss something? or I'am trying to implement the wrong algorithm?

Console output code above
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you are registering your mouse up event to the document. 'this' is referring to the DOM and not to your SliderVersion2Component.

I would try binding your this._mouseUp function to your SliderVersion2Component...

registerEvent(document, 'mouseup', this._mouseUp.bind(this));

Comment: Thnks! you save my day!